# EDT vs. Listener

Tags: java, swing, event-dispatch-thread

Okay, I know I just asked a similar question, but I tried to simplify it, so I used what appeared to be a bad example, one which had a problem I did not expect, thus getting me the answers which didn't solve my question.

I have a setup like this:

I have a method in the EDT. It cycles trough a bunch of JTextAreas, and removes empty ones.

So what's the catch?

Each time JTextArea is removed, a listener is triggered which then visually updates the GUI (pulls all visual object below the JTextArea up).

So what happens? Well, as the loop is being executed, JTextAreas are not being removed visually, they are being added to the EDT que (I'm guessing), and then they are all removed at once after the loop is done. What happens then is that all of the listeners fire at once and mess up the whole GUI.

Since everything is ran on the EDT, I expected the code to act like this:

- Start cycle
- Find an empty JTextArea
- Completly remove an empty JTextArea -> triggers the listener

  - Execute the code in the listener
- Continue the loop
- Find the next empty JTextArea
- Rinse and repeat until end of loop is reached

How can I force my program to act like this?

Should I create a new thread that searches for the blank JTextAreas, and have the removals be done in invokeLater(new Runnable())?
The actual code that does the search is really not CPU intentsive, it only goes trough arrayList of JTextAreas and check is getText().equals(""), so I don't really think that's necessary...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: It's a conceptual question. No SSCCE is needed.

Comment: I can't see removing a bunch of components been the reason that your UI is messed up (I can believe it, but I think there is something else going on).  If you are really worried about the sequence of events, you could use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` instead, which will wait until the `run` method of the `runnable` has completed, unlike `invokeLater` which will place the `runnable` at the end of the event queue and return (almost) immediately...

Comment: @Karlovsky120 Then only expect conceptual answers.  The solutions we come up with may not meet your particular needs

Comment: Only thing I'm interested in is to make sure the element is removed in every possible way the moment the program reaches the .remove() line of code. As it is, the visual removal seems to happen only after the method has ran it's course. Since all of the removals happen at once, all the listeners fire at the same time, accessing and moving other elements at the same time.

Comment: Does your loop contains `revalidate/repaint` calls on the parent container, from which the components are being removed ? That might can be one of the issues, but without the code it's tough to reach a sure shot answer.

Comment: `As it is, the visual removal seems to happen only after the method has ran it's course.` That is correct. Code on the EDT executes sequentially. So when you click on a button to start your processing which in turn does looping, then the GUI doesn't repaint itself until the initial loop has finished executing. If you want to remove 1 component at a time then this implies some kind of animation, which means you should be using a Timer. So each time the Timer fires you find a component and remove it. When there are no more components to remove you stop the Timer.

Answer (score 2):

Remove a single text area.  determine if there are more to remove, if so, queue a task using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` which calls back into the current code.  repeat until all text areas are removed.